# What does sizeof (int) * p semantically mean?

Tags: c, sizeof

What does `sizeof (int) * p` semantically mean? Is it:
1. `sizeof( (int) *p )`
or
2. `( sizeof(int) ) * p`
and what rule makes the expression to be evaluated this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is a unary operator, which has a higher precedence than binary `*`, so the expression `sizeof (int) * p` is parsed as `(sizeof (int)) * p`.  Here's the parse tree:

```
             *
           /   \
       sizeof   p
         |
       (int)
```

**Edit**

From onezero's comment:

> but can't the expression be evaluated like sizeof( (int) *p ) ,as sizeof operator, type-cast operator and *(dereference) operator have same precedence and associates from right to left?

Here's the relevant syntax (from the [ballot draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf) of the C2011 standard):

```
(6.5.3) unary-expression:
    postﬁx-expression
    ++ unary-expression
    -- unary-expression
    unary-operator cast-expression
    sizeof unary-expression
    sizeof ( type-name )
    alignof ( type-name )
```

As you can see, the `(int)` is interpreted as part of the `sizeof` expression, full stop.  It is not interpreted as part of a *cast-expression*.  The syntax doesn't allow `sizeof` to be followed directly by a *cast-expression*; there must be a *unary-operator* (one of `&`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `~`, `!`) between them.

Comment: Maybe you can also link to a Wikipedia article which explains exactly what you just said in one nice table: [C/C++ Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: @JohnBode but can't the expression be evaluated like `sizeof( (int) *p )` ,as sizeof operator, type-cast operator and *(dereference) operator have same precedence and associates from right to left?

Comment: @Alex: ugh.  I wished they'd separated it into two separate tables, one for C and one for C++ (they *are* two different languages, after all).

Comment: @onezero: No. The language grammar simply won't allow such an interpretation.  Once `sizeof` is recognized, then the next token is assumed to be its operand, whether it's a *unary-expression* or the sequence `(` *type-name* `)`.  There's no legal derivation for `sizeof` followed by a *cast-expression*.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't it depend what p is?

```
void main()
{
   int p = 3;

   printf("%d", sizeof(int) *p);
}
```

Will output 12.

```
void main()
{
   char *p = "a";

   printf("%d", sizeof((int) *p));
}
```

Will output 4.

Comment: no it doesn't depends on what p is? In 2nd example you are getting the output as 4 because you have explicitly introduced parenthesis thereby forcing the compiler to evaluate the expression in context relevant(where p is a pointer) way.